# Foreach cannot operate on a method group

Tags: asp.net, treeview, foreach

```
private void PrintRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
            PrintRecursive(tn);
        }
    }
```

I get the error: Foreach cannot operate on a method group. Did you intend to invoke the 'method group'?

Comment: Seems like `Nodes` is a method. How is it declared? If it is a method, you should be calling `foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes())` instead.

Comment: @RedFilter TreeNode class is from metadata. It's from .Net, it's not mine.

Comment: Could you please provide full type name for your TreeNode? It seems you referenced wrong type, loos like from WinForms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using the packaged TreeView control, shouldn't it be `ChildNodes`?:

```
foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.ChildNodes) ...
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem here is that `Nodes` is a method but you use as property :)
So this line of code

```
foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
```

should be

```
foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes())
```

Answer (score 1):

[TreeView.Nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.nodes.aspx) gives a collection of TreeNode objects that represents the root nodes in the TreeView control.

To access the child nodes of a root node, use the [ChildNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.childnodes.aspx) property of the node.

e.g. using for loop

```
void  PrintRecursive(TreeNode node)
{
  for(int i=0; i <node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
  {
    PrintRecursive(node.ChildNodes[i]);
  }
}
```

or using foreach

```
void  PrintRecursive(TreeNode node)
{
  foreach(TreeNode node in node.ChildNodes)
  {
    PrintRecursive(node);
  }
}
```